# Jmeter. Http sampler with random numbers and strings collection elements in json

Tags: json, jmeter

I'm newbie to Jmeter, my http request body is like:

```
{
   "List":{
      "ListAPPInfo":[
         {
            "first_time":"2013-06-24 10:00:00",
            "lasttime":"2013-06-24 10:00:00"
         }
      ],
      "device_id":"015d24a409441203",
      "device_model":"Nexus 7"
   }
}
```

I want to send Http sampler with random parameter like `first_time` value start at 2013-01-01 ends 2013-12-31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to add sort of this tree node:

```
Simple Controller
  |_ HTTP Request Defaults
  |_ Your Request Controller
    |_ Random Variable Year
    |_ Random Variable Month
    |_ Other...
```

Now parameters of your random variable:
Year

```
Random Variable: 
Variable Name: RND_YEAR
Output Format: 0000
Minimum Value: 0000
Maximum Value: 2999
```

Month

```
Random Variable: 
Variable Name: RND_MONTH
Output Format: 00
Minimum Value: 01
Maximum Value: 12
```

Day

```
Random Variable: 
Variable Name: RND_DAY
Output Format: 00
Minimum Value: 01
Maximum Value: 30
```

And other variables.

Please note, count of numbers in Format and Value should be equal.

Now put this kind of text `${RND_VARIABLE}` into `Your Request Controller` request.

Like this:

```
{
   "List":{
      "ListAPPInfo":[
         {
            "first_time":"${RND_YEAR}-${RND_MONTH}-${RND_DAY} 10:00:00",
            "lasttime":"2013-06-24 10:00:00"
         }
      ],
      "device_id":"015d24a409441203",
      "device_model":"Nexus 7"
   }
}
```

Save and start your testplan.

You can use BeanShell processor to generate your random date 
http://justjmeter.blogspot.ru/2012/04/2.html
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html

If you want to substitute random string elements of some collection, you should write your own beanshell function inside of `BeanShell PreProcessor` on java.

```
import java.util.Random;

enum locales {UK, RU};
Random randGenerator = new Random();
int randInt = randGenerator.nextInt(locales.values().length);
vars.put("randomLocale",locales.values()[randInt].toString());
```

Then as usual you paste `${randomLocale}` inside of your request.

Comment: Thanks a lot!What if the random parameter is not number but string ,such as Region: US、UK、JP、CN..etc

Comment: @user2563901 answered above.

Comment: @user2563901 if my answer was helpful, you can accept it, pressing the accept button under voting area of my answer.

Comment: @user2563901 did you do this what i wrote ? I've checked java code. It's getting random elements from locales collection. so if you add beanshell preprocessor into your testplan in usual way, you'll get it work. If you have any questions, please ask.

Comment: i've tried to add a BeanShell PreProcessor on my http request, and did exactly you said ,but the result came out with false, result tree shows my post data didn't receive random parameter ${randomRegion}, is there any step wrong, please advise, if you need to know more information please let me know , thanks again